# Django Running Particular Test

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

In My Project more than one test file and if i run

```
python manage.py tests
```

It takes huge time to complete the test and i don't want this way.

I want only run particular file of test like i have test

```
project/todo/tests/test_todo.py
project/accounts/tests/test_signup.py
project/todo/tests/test_archive.py
```

and lots more like above these:

Now i want to run only `project/todo/tests/test_todo.py` How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do `python manage.py test project.todo.tests.test_todo`. Observe the difference here instead of giving it as a file, you can give it as a package. If you want to run a particular test case in a test suite, you can go ahead in the same way. `python manage.py test project.todo.tests.test_todo.TestSuiteClass.TestCase`.

Comment: @mamuncode if this solves the problem, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a particular test by using the following command.

```
python manage.py test -nk appname.test_folder.test_file

-n, --nomigrations    Tells Django to NOT use migrations and create all
                        tables directly.
-k, --keepdb          Preserves the test DB between runs.
```